# Number of steps taken to split a number

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I cannot get my head around this:

Say I got a number 9. I want to know the minimum steps needed to split it so that no number is greater than 3.

I always thought that the most efficient way is to halve it every loop.
So, 9 -> 4,5 -> 2,2,5 -> 2,2,2,3 so 3 steps in total. However, I just realised a smarter way: 9 -> 3,6 -> 3,3,3 which is 2 steps only...

After some research, the number of steps is in fact (n-1)/target, where target=3 in my example.

Can someone please explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: There's no particular reason to think breaking pieces in half would be the most efficient way. If you try to prove that it's the most efficient way, you'll quickly run into reasons why your proof doesn't work; that might help you understand it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to cut a stick of length `L` into pieces of size no greater than `S`, we need `ceiling(L/S)` pieces. Each time we make a new cut, we increase the number of pieces by 1. It doesn't matter what order we make the cuts in, only where. For example, if we want to break a stick of length 10 into pieces of size 2 or less:

```
 -------------------
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

we should cut it in the following places:

```
 ---|---|---|---|---
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

and any order of cuts is fine, as long as these are the cuts that are made. On the other hand, if we start by breaking it in half:

```
 ---------|---------
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

we have made a cut that isn't part of the optimal solution, and we have wasted our time.

Comment: It starts to make sense...thanks. It does make no sense to cut it in the middle. Don't know why I was thinking about that...

Answer (score 1):

I really like @user2357112's explanation of why cutting in half is not the right first step, but I also like algebra, and you can prove that `ceil(n / target) - 1` is optimal using induction.

Let's prove first that you can always do it in `ceil(n / target) - 1` steps.

If `n <= target`, obviously no step are required, so the formula works. Suppose `n > target`. Split `n` into `target` and `n - target` (1 step). By induction, `n - target` can be split in `ceil((n - target)/target) - 1` steps. Therefore the total number of steps is

```
  1 + ceil((n - target) / target) - 1

= 1 + ceil(n / target) - target/target - 1

= ceil(n / target) - 1.
```

Now let's prove that you can't do it in fewer than `ceil(n / target) - 1` steps. This is obvious if `n <= target`. Suppose `n > target` and the first step is `n -> a + b`. By induction, `a` requires at least `ceil(a / target) - 1` steps and `b` requires at least `ceil(b / target) - 1` steps. The minimum number of steps required is therefore at least

```
   1 + ceil(a / target) - 1 + ceil(b / target) - 1

>= ceil((a + b) / target) - 1                using ceil(x) + ceil(y) >= ceil(x + y)

 = ceil(n / target) - 1                      using a + b = n
```

Answer (score 0):

Every n can be thought of as a priority queue of \lfloor n/target \rfloor target elements placed first on the queue and one element whose value is n%target.  Every time you remove an element from the queue, you place it back on the queue.  Remove all but the last element: you have clearly removed \lfloor (n-1)/target \rfloor elements.  If the last element is less than or equal to the target, we are done.  If it is greater than the target, we have a contradiction.  So, after \lfloor (n-1)/target \rfloor steps we have a queue consisting only of elements less than or equal to target.